# Express column of a matrix as a linear combination of other columns

Tags: matrices

A matrix C is given as such:
$C = \begin{bmatrix}1&3&2&1&1&3\\2&6&5&4&4&9\\1&3&3&3&4&8\\3&9&9&9&10&20\end{bmatrix}$

Suppose I wanted to express column 4 as a linear combination of the other columns in C. I found the echelon form of C, which is:
$U = \begin{bmatrix}1&3&2&1&1&3\\0&0&1&2&2&3\\0&0&0&0&1&2\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Therefore, $\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\-2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ is in the nullspace of C, which means column 4 = (-3)column 1 + (2)column 3 **for the columns in matrix U.** However, the coefficient seems to hold for matrix C as well, **but doesn't elimination change column space?** I understand that it must be possible to express column 4 as linear combination of column 1, column 3, and column 5 for matrix C, since they're the pivot columns, but wouldn't you have to recalculate the coefficients? So does this always hold true and could you explain it in simple terms. Thanks.

Comment: It does indeed hold for $C$ as well as $U$. If you perform only row operations on $C$, then you haven't changed the equality in the column equation you found, so it will still work. (why is that so? Hint: The row operations change the basis, but not the relationship between the columns.)

Comment: Row operations change the column space, but they don't change the null space.  The null space is the part with the information of which columns can be combined to give you the others.

Comment: So is this right: As long as I only perform row operations on a matrix, the relations between the columns will hold since the nullspace hasn't changed?

Comment: The point is, all 3 types of elementary row operations do not change the validity of any linear identity involving the columns (this is actually pretty easy to prove). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relations between columns of a matrix $A$ can be expressed as $AX=0$, for some column $X$ (since $AX = X_1 col_1(A) + X_2 col_2(A) + ... + X_n col_n(A)$).

Row operations correspond to multiplications to the left by invertible matrices. Hence by performing a sequence of row operations, a matrix $A$ is transformed into some $B = UA$, with $U$ invertible.

Then: $BX= 0 \Longleftrightarrow (UA)X = 0 \Longleftrightarrow U(AX)=0 \Longleftrightarrow AX=0$, because $U$ is invertible. Hence the linear relations satisfied by the columns of a matrix are preserved through row operations.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it much clearer now.